# compile Vue 3 component for HMR

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, webpack-hmr, vue3-sfc-loader

`vuejs/vue-hot-reload-api` for Vue2 accept simple object with component options.

Vue3 have built-in HMR support and it needs a different approach. I can't figure out how properly update component.

What kind of data is need for `__VUE_HMR_RUNTIME__.createRecord()`?

And how to compile updated component again for `__VUE_HMR_RUNTIME__.reload()`

I think both functions need `render` function. But it is created when the component is loaded to dom or something.
When I use something like below, `render()` function is not present in `cmp`.

```
let cmp = defineComponent({template: '<div>test</div>})
let inst = Vue.component('test', cmp)
```

When I use  component in parent component, render() is compiled and included in `cmp`.

But I cant register changed component same way because Vue3 show warn that this component is already registered.

How to compile updated component below and use it in `__VUE_HMR_RUNTIME__.reload()`?

```
let updatedCmp = defineComponent({template: '<div>test Me!</div>'})
```

I tried vue's `compile()` function, but it doesn't work for me...

***I assume this is the only way to replace a component with a modified version in runtime? :)***

Comment: What is your purpose when doing HMR yourself? I think Vue is doing it really well.

Comment: I want to replace old component with an updated one. I easily achieved this in vue2 with vue-hot-reload-api.

Comment: I mean Vue did it for us very well. HMR works with vue-cli or vite by default without any config. I didn't see any cases we need to do HMR manually.

Comment: with dev-server/vue-cli I can update locally edited component. Not virtually created component.

Comment: Can you make a [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?